# Exported all MySQL databases to a single file

Tags: mysql, sql

Accidentally I exported all my mySQL databases to a single .sql file. I want to create those databases again in my development environment. When I try to import the file via PHPMyAdmin I get the following error message:
[image]

What should I do? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error, it says no Database selected.
You need to create an identical Database and import it from their.

You cannot just import a whole database, as it does not work.

Let me know if this solves,

Bryce

*also, make sure the files are speared by database, as this could make the error also, as the import can only import one in one file

Comment: How to do this? "make sure the files are speared by database". I have all my databases in a single file...